# How do I set a listStore model on pre-created listbox from Glade?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glade

Apparently the "proper" way to have items in a [GTKListBox or Treeview](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html) is constructing with a listStore model, in the constructor. What if I want to use Glade GUI project, in which a list box is already created, and referenced by `builder.get_object("appsDocumentListBox")`?

Can I set the model after Gtk.builder created the window, or is there a better way to do this?

I'm also wondering what the performance improvement is of using the ListStore vs manually adding with `row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()`, adding contents and setting `ListBox.add(row)`? (which does work from a Glade-builder Python window)

Unlike Treeview, apparently Listbox won't set a model after constructor?

```
>>> l = Gtk.ListBox()
>>> l.set_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ListBox' object has no attribute 'set_model'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two things up. You can create a `GtkListBox` and add `GtkListBoxRow`s to it. There is no need for an extra model here.

There are also `GtkListStore` and `GtkTreeStore`. Both of them use a `GtkTreeView`. The ListStore has a flat hierarchy and the TreeStore can be nested.
The GtkTreeView has a `set_model` function so you can set a model after you created it. You can also create the corresponding model directly in Glade.

If you have complicated widgets that you want to add, the `GtkListBox` is better suited. For a lot of data which is supposed to be sorted or hierarchically structured, I would rather use a `GtkTreeView` with a corresponding model.

Comment: How do you create a model for a listbox in Glade? Yes, I know you can add rows to listbox, but how would  you handle activating a row, saving info in a structure?

Comment: You can add any widget to the ListBox e.g. a `GtkBox`. The ListBoxRow will be created automatically in between. To handle the activating you can connect to the `row-activated` signal and I don't understand what you mean with "saving info in a structure".

Comment: I didn't know that, but I had added a row to a ListBox, and thought that was the wrong way to do it. On the `row-activated` signal it just passes the ListBox and the row, so there's no obvious way to get at the data you had when you created that visible title.

Comment: You can subclass your own ListBoxRow and provide your own method for it or do something like `get_child().get_text()` depending on your widget stacking.